# Reverse an array in assembly language (68HC12)

Tags: assembly

I need the array to be copied and reversed. The only thing I can do is copy, but I dont understand how to reverse it. Help me please.

That is what I have for now

```
STACK                   equ     $2000

                        org     $1000
Source_Array            db      $01, $FF, $13, $22, $12, $25, $12, $FE
End_Source

Destination_Array       ds      Destination_Array-Source_Array 
End_Destination
                        org     $2000
Start                   lds     #STACK
                        ldx     #Source_Array
                        ldy     #Destination_Array
Loop                    ldaa    1,x+
                        staa    1,y+

                        cpx     #End_Source
                        bne     Loop
                        swi
                        end
```

Comment: I need to copy the values from the source array and place them reversed to destination. The destination array should be: FE, 12, 25, 12, 22, 13, ff, 01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the array reversed should be as simple as setting `y` up to the end of the second array and using pre-decrement instead of post-increment for storage; (hoping I'm getting the pre-decrement correct from memory)

```
STACK                   equ     $2000

                        org     $1000
Source_Array            db      $01, $FF, $13, $22, $12, $25, $12, $FE
End_Source

Destination_Array       ds      Destination_Array-Source_Array 
End_Destination
                        org     $2000
Start                   lds     #STACK
                        ldx     #Source_Array
                        ldy     #End_Destination
Loop                    ldaa    1,x+
                        staa    1,-y

                        cpx     #End_Source
                        bne     Loop
                        swi
                        end
```

Comment: I have one more question, may be you can give me a hint, how to sort a reversed array? And thank you one more time

Comment: @AnaF You may want to add a new question for the sort with a bit more detail on exactly what you need. For example, here are many many sort algorithms to choose from. Asking a new question will also draw more attention from other people than just me, so you may get a better/faster answer :)

Comment: Ok :) Thank you!))

Comment: please look it if you have free time. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441825/68hc12-sort-an-array-in-assembly